# Rendering different navbars based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue with conditional rendering. I have created a state that I test to see if true or false, each would have a different navbar rendered: 1 for a normal user and 1 for an admin. I've determined that my login component works correctly because when I click submit on my login page, it send the correct data to switch the "isLoggedIn" state in the app.js to true. The issue that arises here is that the navbar does not change and when I go to the base page "localhost:8081/" the url shows the correct page that should show when logged in but it isnt rendered. I will post my code below, please let me know if you have any ideas or need more info!

**App.js**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false
    }
  }

  handleLogonChange(b) {
    if(b) {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: true
      });
    }
  }

render() {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      return (
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a href="/menus" className="navbar-brand">
              Blue Devil Cafe Online
          </a>
            <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/menus"} className="nav-link">
                  Menus
              </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/addmenu"} className="nav-link">
                  Add Menu
              </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/menuitems"} className="nav-link">
                  Menu Items
              </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/addmenuitem"} className="nav-link">
                  Add Menu Item
              </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          </nav>

          <div className="container mt-3">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={["/", "/menuitems"]} component={MenuItemList} />
              <Route exact path="/addmenuitem" component={AddMenuItem} />
              <Route path="/menuitems/:id" component={MenuItem} />

              <Route exact path={"/menus"} component={MenuList} />
              <Route exact path="/addmenu" component={AddMenu} />
              <Route path="/menus/:id" component={Menu} />
            </Switch>
          </div>

        </div>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a href="/menus" className="navbar-brand">
              Blue Devil Cafe Online
          </a>
            <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                  Home
              </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/calendar"} className="nav-link">
                  Calendar
              </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/cart"} className="nav-link">
                  Cart
              </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                  Login
              </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          </nav>

          <div className="container mt-3">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={"/home"} component={Home} />
              <Route exact path={"/calendar"} component={Calendar} />
              <Route exact path={"/cart"} component={Cart} />
              <Route exact path={"/login"} render={() => <Login handleLogonChange={this.handleLogonChange}/>} />
            </Switch>
          </div>

        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

This is the user nav:
[image: UserNav]

This is the admin nav:
[image: AdminNav]

This is also the post where I asked days ago on sending data between components:
[How to pass data between 2 classes in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900925/how-to-pass-data-between-2-classes-in-reactjs/64901115)?

Comment: Could you add additional details which might help us to identify issue.

Comment: @TheMisir I added the 2 functions from above the render, there really isnt much else. Do you have any speculations?

Comment: You could try rendering something like `render() { return <span>{this.state.isLoggedIn ? 'logged in' : 'not logged in'}</span> }` just to check if the issue is related to this component or something else.

Comment: I think I have a the answer, but since we don't have the CSS you are using, even if its bootstrap, can you show images? before login, after login and the page you talked about

Comment: but other than that, I think by the code, the problem is simple, the render is called only once, its the JSX that changes not the render function, you need to put the condition inside the JSX, that way it will change, or you can use `componentDidUpate` function

Comment: the render gets called wayyy before your code gets to `handleLogonChange`,  that is why I am guessing its not responding like it should, the solution is simple for this, but more images needed

Comment: You are correct after I did some testing, it seems the state actually is not being updated. I will be editing the post with more images of what it looks like now and what it looks like after.

Comment: @AKC So I found and fixed the issue, I hadn't binded the functions to the class constructor yet. Thanks for the help with how I should test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want but i'd suggest the first thing you might wanna do is changing the navigations to their own components. Something like this.

```js
const AdminNav = () => (
  <div>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a href="/menus" className="navbar-brand">
        Blue Devil Cafe Online
      </a>
      <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/menus"} className="nav-link">
            Menus
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/addmenu"} className="nav-link">
            Add Menu
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/menuitems"} className="nav-link">
            Menu Items
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/addmenuitem"} className="nav-link">
            Add Menu Item
          </Link>
        </li>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div className="container mt-3">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={["/", "/menuitems"]} component={MenuItemList} />
        <Route exact path="/addmenuitem" component={AddMenuItem} />
        <Route path="/menuitems/:id" component={MenuItem} />

        <Route exact path={"/menus"} component={MenuList} />
        <Route exact path="/addmenu" component={AddMenu} />
        <Route path="/menus/:id" component={Menu} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const UserNav = () => (
  <div>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a href="/menus" className="navbar-brand">
        Blue Devil Cafe Online
      </a>
      <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/calendar"} className="nav-link">
            Calendar
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/cart"} className="nav-link">
            Cart
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
            Login
          </Link>
        </li>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div className="container mt-3">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/home"} component={Home} />
        <Route exact path={"/calendar"} component={Calendar} />
        <Route exact path={"/cart"} component={Cart} />
        <Route
          exact
          path={"/login"}
          render={() => <Login handleLogonChange={this.handleLogonChange} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
);

// Your render function will look something like this.
render() {
    return this.state.isLoggedIn ? <AdminNav /> : <UserNav />;
}
```

Then to debug this issue you can log the `isLoggedIn` state, you also didn't mention how are you updating the state. so as long as the state is updating as it should this would work.

Comment: I'll try this out right now, I am updating the isLoggedIn state from my login file which is a child of the app.js so I have a props statement there that is handling the change in the app.js state.

Comment: is the state being updated correctly ?, i mean try logging you state in the render method and check if it is actually updating correctly

Comment: You are correct. After doing some more testing I found that the state actually is not being changed by the child component correctly.

Comment: This helped me solve the issue I was having for this question I had, as for the other issue that arose I figured that out myself too so I am marking this correct.